# Run program inside a virtual monitor in order to limit its size?

Tags: display, 4k-resolution, high-dpi, 1080p

I have a program than need to be runed in 1080p to work properly.

My monitor is 4k and i'd like to use it this way.

I have tried all windows options to prevent bug with high dpi monitor but none are working and I was thinking maybe there is a way to limit the program size to 1920*1080 or maybe using a virtual monitor that would act like a tool and I would run my program inside it?

If you have any idea or soft to recomand please let me know.

PS: I am using windows 10 / 64bits

Comment: One option you could try is to install the Application Compatibility Toolkit which is part of the ADK - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install. You could try applying a "fix" to the application in the "Compatability Administrator" tool that gets installed. There is a 32 and 64-bit version, you want to launch the same bitness as the application. Essentially you can author a shim file (.sdb) that applies to the application.This can be installed with `sdbinst patch.sdb` and it will appear in Programs and Features. There are DPI settings in there that might help.